# Find smallest key in binary tree in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

How would one go about finding the smallest key in a binary tree? If it was a binary search tree, the smallest value would be on the far left, and the biggest on the far right (if I haven't misunderstood), but a binary tree doesn't have that ordering.

I can't seem to think of a good way to solve this problem. Would be great if anyone could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is probably easiest to solve recursively.

- You find the smallest key of the left sub-tree.
- You find the smallest key of the right sub-tree.
- you compare the former two elements to each other and to the current node's element, and return the smallest of the 3 elements.

Here's some pseudo code :

```
KeyType getSmallestKey (Node root)
{
    minLeft = MAX_VALUE
    minRight = MAX_VALUE
    if root.hasLeftChild
        minLeft = getSmallestKey(root.left)
    if root.hasRightChild
        minRight = getSmallestKey(root.right)
    return min (minLeft, minRight, root.getKey)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you also write it in pseudocode? I get the idea, but the implementation is worse... I struggle alot with the use of recursion.